# iTextSharp aligning PDFP table with paragraph within margins of a document

Tags: c#, pdf, alignment, itext

I'm generating a PDF document like this:

```
  string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);

            Document doc = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4,50,50,120,40);


            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(path+"\\Invoices\\Test.pdf", FileMode.Create));
            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
            table.WidthPercentage = 100;
            table.DefaultCell.BorderWidth = 0;
            table.DefaultCell.HasBorder(iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
            table.AddCell(new PdfPCell() { HorizontalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT, Phrase = new Phrase("Text to the left"), BorderColor = BaseColor.WHITE, BorderWidth = 0 });
            table.AddCell(new PdfPCell() { HorizontalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_RIGHT, Phrase = new Phrase("Text to the right"), BorderColor = BaseColor.WHITE, BorderWidth = 0 });

            //   table.AddCell(new PdfPCell("Text to the left", PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
            //  table.AddCell(new PdfPCell("Text to the left", PdfPCell.ALIGN_RIGHT));
            document.add(table);

            doc.Open();
            Paragraph p = new Paragraph("This is a first text above \n \n", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8.0f, BaseColor.BLACK));
            doc.Add(p);
            doc.Add(table);
            doc.Close();
```

Which produces a document like this:

[image]

Do you guys notice that the text inside the paragrap and the table are not aligned perfectly to the left?

How could I fix this with or without adding the first text into the table itself (both options are fine for me)

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Anyone, guys?  :)

Comment: Already inpatient after less than 15 minutes? Come on, on a Sunday people just might have other things to do...

Comment: @mkl Sry about that, yeah u have a good point :) I'm working on a solution to just simply add the first text into a table and then make a few extra lines on the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the cells padding to zero to remove that tiny space on the left, like:

```
new PdfPCell { PaddingLeft = 0 }
```

Btw you can remove this BorderColor and BorderWidth and DefaultCell stuff. Just set:

```
Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER
```

on the cell properties to remove the border.

Comment: Excellent it works! Thanks! 

Btw. How would I remove any white space produced by the table/cells inside the table ? :)

Comment: Padding = 0 and if not already false by default, set: UseAscender = false, UseDescender = false on the cells

Comment: Thanks @COeDev, does this same applies for line separators ? I have two set, one above and below the table, do they produce any unwanted padding ?

Comment: Test and see? ;)  What kind of line separators are you using?

Comment: like this:             Chunk linebreak2 = new Chunk(new LineSeparator(1f, 100f, BaseColor.BLACK, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, 0));
 :D